# Can't create a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regex so that it captures these:

```
/articles/123
/articles/123/something
/articles/123/something_else doesnt' matter
```

and doesn't these:

```
/articles
/articles/
/articles/123a
```

where 123 is integer

I tried this: 
  `%r{^/articles/\d+}` and `%r{^/articles/\d+/*}` but it also captured this `/articles/1a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^\/articles\/\d+(\/.*|$)
```

Conditionally match the end of the string using the `$` character.

Here's a regex101 to play around with: https://regex101.com/r/dA1wD4/1